# How to add extra actions for endpoint routing in django rest frameworks

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django rest framework, and I'm trying to learn drf. I didn't know how to achieve this features. I want some things like(Extra Actions) as shown in screenshot to navigate all the endpoint.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example from official DRF documentation:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.data['password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action(detail=False)
    def recent_users(self, request):
        recent_users = User.objects.all().order_by('-last_login')

        page = self.paginate_queryset(recent_users)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(recent_users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

For more, please visit: [Viewset actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions)